# How can I get the average ItemPerUser / Total tems?

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't get this to show me the correct result of Percentages.

| ID_Home | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Home 1 |
| 2 | Home 2 |

| ID_user | Name | ID_Home |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1 |
| 2 | Jane | 1 |
| 3 | Paul | 1 |
| 4 | Paul | 2 |

I'm trying to do a query where my result would be the Percentage of the users per home.

| Home | Percentage of Customers in Home |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | .75 |
| 2 | .25 |

I believe I'm not using the Count statements correctly.

```
SELECT u.name, (Count(DISTINCT h.ID_Home) / Count(DISTINCT u.Name)) AS Percentage
FROM Home h JOIN
    User u
    ON u.ID_Home = h.ID_Home
GROUP BY h.ID_Home;
```

Comment: It would be MySQL, just modified thanks.

Comment: My bad, I had to translate this, missed a few edits.

Comment: There is no ID_Home in your User table... this is why you should ensure you have a [mre] **before** you ask a question... which you naturally get if you create test DDL+DML.

Comment: Sorry about that, had to edit it throughly, it should be good now. I'm basically not getting the correct values on my result. On the script in which I have 4 users at Home 1 and 2 users at Home 2. I'm getting Home 1 = 0.25, Home 2 = 0.5.

Comment: Is it possible that homes have *no* users and would you want to count those homes in the average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you don't have a count of **all** rows, which is necessary in order to calculate a percentage. You can do that using a window function as follows:

```
create table Home (ID_Home int, Name varchar(32));
create table User (ID_User int, Name varchar(32), ID_Home int);

insert into Home (ID_Home, Name)
values
(1, 'Home 1'),
(2, 'Home 2');

insert into User (ID_User, Name, ID_Home)
values
(1, 'John', 1),
(2, 'Jane', 1),
(3, 'Paul', 1),
(4, 'Philip', 2);

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT h.Name, u.ID_User
      , COUNT(u.ID_User) OVER () TotalRows
    FROM Home h
    INNER JOIN User u ON u.ID_Home = h.ID_Home
)
SELECT
  Name, CAST((COUNT(ID_User) * 1.0) / TotalRows AS decimal(9,2)) AS Percentage
FROM cte
GROUP BY Name, TotalRows;
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8d516083c437cf63118612bc14988bbe)

Returns

| Name | Percentage |
| --- | --- |
| Home 1 | 0.75 |
| Home 2 | 0.25 |

Note: If you setup your questions like this i.e. including the DDL+DML and your attempt you can not only ensure that you are providing a working example, but you make it much easier for people to assist you.

Answer (score 1):

On MySQL 8+, I would aggregate and then use `SUM()` as an analytic function to normalize the counts:

```sql
SELECT
    ID_Home,
    COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS percentage
FROM Home
GROUP BY ID_Home;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You need the total number of users for the wanted calculation, a way to achieve this is:

```
SELECT
      name
    , (homes * 100.0 / u.total) AS percentage
FROM (
    SELECT
           h.name
         , Count(DISTINCT h.ID_Home) AS homes
    FROM Home h
    JOIN User u ON u.ID_Home = h.ID_Home
    GROUP BY h.name
    ) AS g
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT count(*) AS total
    FROM users
    ) AS u
```